# weird A showing up from database space

Tags: mysql, sql

Newbie here looking for some help on my Data base and what I thought was a SQL TRIM statement.

I am getting lots of the weird A characters on my website in the public and admin update views of a database query where the blank spaces are in the table on the server.  I have 780 records in the table with 11 records each and have trailing space(s) in about 85% of the records/fields.

I have tried several variations in the: Run SQL query/queries on database.  Here is the exact MySQL code from several working variations that all end with 0 rows affected:

```
UPDATE inventory3 SET'Price' = RTRIM('Price')
```

The action executes but, I'm missing the logic to actually execute- the reply is:

```
 0 row(s) affected. ( Query took 0.0025 sec ) 
 UPDATE inventory3 SET `Price` = RTRIM( `Price` )
```

Deleting those spaces one field at a time per record is a real pain.

Any help? My character set in the php page is charset=iso-8859-1. What's the solution, is there another direction I can go to solve the weird A character from showing on the web?

Comment: Are the quotes a typo?

Comment: Single quotes in MySQL represent the literal values. When you ask to `SET'Price' = RTRIM('Price')` you're not asking to update a column. Columns need to be encased in backticks.

Comment: FreshPrince, Awesome, did not know that's what they were but I was getting there by adding the field name via some selection-choice mechanism provided by the phpAdmin screen.  So, the literal version above is a retype with apostrophes subbed for back ticks.  I was able to run with correct syntax, but no affect.

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks for column names.

Comment: Finally got IT to work - 780 rows! Thank you, syntax can be such a strict task master!!

Answer (score 0):

`MySQL` will only report rows as affected if actual update took place (i. e. new value differs from the old).

Most probably, you don't have leading or trailing spaces in your data anymore now that you have run your update several times.

Comment: Ok, but that should get rid of the weird A things which still exist in the rows/records of which I have not individually updated and backspaced over the extra space.  Any other thoughts maybe?